# HAPROXY 2.0.6- Limiting Http Request Rate for DDOS Prevention using Stick Tables

Tags: security, haproxy

I was trying to limit the http-request rate to backend nginx server via haproxy using
     "stick-table" but as soon as i restart haproxyafter configuration it seems like"track-sc0"
      is not accepted .Can anybody help me on this? Following is the snap of "haproxy.cfg" 
      and "haproxy.log"

```
   frontend proxy_front
     http-request track-sc0 src table proxy_back
     http-request deny if { sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 100 }
     default_backend proxy_back

   backend proxy_back
     mode http
     stick-table type ip size 100K expire 10s store http_req_rate(10s)
     server Nginx x.x.x.x:x maxconn 10000


Following is the log generated by haproxy

May 20 15:36:45 ext-proxy1 haproxy-systemd-wrapper: [ALERT] 140/153645 (79155) : parsing 
[/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:35]: 'http-request' expects 'allow', 'deny', 'auth', 'redirect', 
'tarpit', 'add-header', 'set-header', 'replace-header', 'replace-value', 'set-nice', 'set-tos',
'set-mark', 'set-log-level', 'add-acl', 'del-acl', 'del-map', 'set-map', but got 'track-sc0'.

May 20 15:36:45 ext-proxy1 haproxy-systemd-wrapper: [ALERT] 140/153645 (79155) : Error(s)  
found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

May 20 15:36:45 ext-proxy1 haproxy-systemd-wrapper: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit,  
haproxy RC=1
```

Comment: I think you first need to define the stick table and then you are able to use it.

Comment: If I am not wrong ,isn't the second line in backend section has the stick-table defined.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using your config; I created a new configuration, added bind and mode to the `frontend` and started `haproxy` (2.1.4) and seems to work. Can you post the full config?

Comment: IonutTicus, I have solved my past issue but as per the config haproxy is not denying any of the http-request even if the request limit has exceeded the threshold of 10 request/sec. Can u help on that?